# Regular expression for "not belonging to" in OCaml

Tags: regex, ocaml, lex, lexer

I would like to define `non-line-termination-character = <any character other than %x000D / %x000A>` in `lexer.mll`. I have tried `let non_line_termination_character = [^('\x0D' '\x0A')]`, but it gave me a syntax error.

I think `let non_line_termination_character = [^'\x0D'] intersect [^'\x0A']` would work, but I don't know how to express `intersect`.

Could anyone help?

PS: The rule is at `12.2.4  Regular expressions` of : http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual026.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of a character set in ocamllex doesn't allow parentheses.  The following works for me:

```
let non_line_termination_character = [^ '\x0d' '\x0a' ]
```

There's no general operator for intersecting regular expressions in ocamllex.  But for two character sets a and b you can write `a # (a # b)`.

```
let nona = [^ 'a']
let nonb = [^ 'b']
let nonab = nona # (nona # nonb)
```

(Weirdly, my tests show this works for every character set I try, except it fails for your specific example of non-CR and non-LF.  It actually seems like a bug.  But maybe I'm missing something obvious.)

Answer (score 2):

The set described by `[^'\x0D']` includes `'\x0A'` and vice-versa, so the union of the two sets includes everything.  I think this is what you were trying for:

```
[^'\x0D' '\x0A']
```